# Electron velocity in hydrogen

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics

I was speculating over the feasibility of myon catalysed fusion.
Somehow I drifted away from that a little, and I was wondering if one can find a quantum-mechanical expression for the velocity of an electron in a bound state like hydrogen?
I guess that I'm probably mixing real quantum-mechanics and "bohrian-quantum-mechanics" very badly here. But still I would like to know.

Thanks for your enlightenment :)

Comment: Yes, you are using Bohr-ian thoughts which are not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can define velocity as $v=\frac{\sqrt{\langle \hat{p}^2 \rangle}}{m_e} $. For ground state $v=Z\alpha$.

Comment: You *can*, but you *shouldn't*. Or at a minimum you shouldn't do so in the presence of beginners. Because they'll misunderstand what it means every time.

Comment: Then why don't you tell me what it means? Also, I'm not really a beginner. But I just noticed that in qm lectures we never talked about something like the velocity of an electron. Of course I took into consideration that there are many reasons why a "velocity of an electron" does not make sense. But also I thought about the uncertainty principle which would imply that some sort of momentum does exist (-> velocity). I wouldn't mind if you give me an elaborate treatment (or link). It may even include qft (although, there I am really a beginner) if necessary.

Comment: @F.Ha The uncertainty principle is why this doesn't represent an answer to your question (and why there *isn't* an answer). Neither position nor momentum commute with the Hamiltonian of this system, so neither have a well defined value for states characterized by good quantum number of the system. They only have distributions. But that means that what Veritas proposes represents the expected result for an average over an ensemble of measurements. That's experimentally well defined, but it doesn't tell you anything definite about a single example of the system.

Comment: Beginners should also remember that a bound state is typically a stationary state. This means that electron is not moving anywhere so you cannot interpret velocity in a classical sense as a derivative of position over time.

Comment: @Veritas I'm aware of that fact. That was what I intended to say when i outlined that I can imagine many reasons why a "velocity" does not make any sense.  Then let me ask sth. else: Did you ever hear of the "inert pair effect"? It's a well known effect in chemistry (maybe have a look on it). And it uses the model that electron move on their trajectories with the speed of light. I know that's a fully bohrian approach. But still this behaviour is proven experimentally. What would then the total qm approach say to that?

Comment: Inert pair effect is related to some heavy elements. For high values of Z the velocity as I defined it becomes close to 1 (speed of light). At this point you have to solve the Dirac equation because  relativistic corrections are large. With Dirac equation there are additional complications to define velocity. See e.g. http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node498.html